# Concatenate ORC partition files on disk?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-athena, orc

I am using Spark 2.3 to convert some CSV data to ORC for use with Amazon Athena; it is working fine! Athena works best with files that are not too small so, after manipulating the data a bit, I am using Spark to coalesce the partitions into a single partition before writing to disk, like so:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.orc("out.orc", compression='zlib', mode='append')
```

This results in a single ORC file that is an optimal file size for use with Athena. However, the coalesce step takes a *very* long time. It adds about 33% to the total amount of time to convert the data!

This is obviously due to the fact that Spark cannot parallelize the coalesce step when saving to a single file. When I create the same number of partitions as there are CPUs available, the ORC write out to disk is much faster!

My question is, can I parallelize the ORC write to disk and then concatenate the files somehow? This would allow me to parallelize the write and merge the files without having to compress everything on a single CPU?

Comment: Athena reads from S3, so file sizes aren't important, right? It's only the total quantity of them

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing though. Athena is slow if I have 200, 800K files vs a single 160M file.

Comment: Well, you could coalesce some higher number instead of 1

Comment: Sure, but that is not ideal. I am going off Amazon's recommendation that each S3 Object should be at least 128MB

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/

Comment: My point is that `coalesce(1)` must run on one machine in some CPU . You cannot parallelize it unless you make it a bigger number. And even if you do make it larger, then you need another Spark app to coalesce those to make a single file

Comment: OK, so then you are certain that there is no simple way to concatenate the partition files on disk? They must be coalesced by Spark? The majority of the time is spent in ZLIB so I was hoping I could parallelize the write but then concatenate the files afterward. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: I don't really know the internals / semantics of where/when files are processed, I just know coalesce and repartition are commonly used for this particular problem, although I've also seen it done in Pig and Hive where you read one table and convert/write to another format